# python regex re.sub with strings

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to use regex expressions to build a word filter.
Currently, i have something in this form:

```
value = re.sub(r'(([q])[ ]*[w][ ]*[e][ ]*[r])', r'\2***', value, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

I would like to be able to do something like

```
value = regex_gen("qwer", value)
```

where my regex_gen function looks like:

```
def regex_gen(filter_word, string):
first = 0
regex = "r'("
regex_result = "r'"
for c in filter_word:
    if first == 0:
        regex += "([" + c + "])"
        regex_result += "\2"
        first += 1
    else:
        regex += "[ ]*[" + c + "]"
        regex_result += "*"
regex += ")'"
regex_result += "'"
final = re.sub(regex, regex_result, string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
return final
```

but my regex_gen function isn't working
so far, i am only accounting for white spaces in between the characters and character case. if other approaches to a word filter are easier to implement than that would work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have `r'...'` with your variable `regex`  and `regex_results`. Change the code so that it doesn't add those characters on it. For example replace:

`regex = "r'("`           **into**     `regex = "("`
`regex_result = "r'"`     **into**     `regex_result = ""`
`regex += ")'"`           **into**     `regex += ")"` 
**remove** `regex_result += "'"`

And replace `\2` with `\\2`. For example:

```
regex_result += "\\2"
```

Now run your code again.

Comment: wwouldn't that disable the raw string for regex inputs?

Comment: @user3444314 `r''` works when you places it around free texts. But here you are placing this inside a string, hence its treated as nothing but a string.